# Problem with the output of the Nested JSON in Mat-table

Tags: json, angular, nested, backend, mat-table

I have a Nested JSON and I want to output it to Mat-Table... Can you guys help me with this, please?

I can output the json susa, how do I output mandantKagAccountEntity?

My code:

```
// Nested JSON

{
    "success": true,
    "susa": [
        {
            "accountlinevaluesId": 1,
            "accountlineId": 1,
            "mandantKagId": 660,
            "mandantAccountsId": 1,
            "period": "7",
            "accountNumber": 27,
            "name": "EDV-Hardware/Software",
            "amount": 55.16859,
            "mandantKagAccountEntity": {
                "mandantKagId": 660,
                "mandantId": 1,
                "kagNumber": 2000,
                "kagText": "A. I. 1. EDV-Software"
            }
        },
] }
```

```
// test.component.ts

private loadData() {
    const yearString = this.year ? `${this.year}` : `${new Date().getFullYear()}`;
    this.balanceListService.getDataForAllMonth(yearString).subscribe(
      (resp: any) => {
        const data = resp.success ? resp.susa : null;
        if (null !== data && data) {
         .... }
}
}
```

Comment: Ping. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what exactly you want to pass to mat-table.
If it's an array of the nested property `mandantKagAccountEntity`, then this should do the trick:

```
const data = resp.success ? resp.susa.map((item) => item.mandantKagAccountEntity) : null;
```

If you only want the very first occurrence of `mandantKagAccountEntity`, then you don't have to iterate over the entire nested object:

```
const data = resp.success ? resp.susa[0]?.mandantKagAccountEntity : null;
```

// EDIT: OP had a misleading question. He actually wants to display the entire data, including the nested object. Here's the answer to that:

`displayedColumns` is being used by mat-table to define which columns to show. You can edit the names to your liking.

```
displayedColumns: string[] = [
  'accountlinevaluesId',
  'accountlineId',
  'mandantKagId',
  'mandantAccountsId',
  'period',
  'accountNumber',
  'name',
  'amount',
  'mandantKagAccountEntity-mandantKagId',
  'mandantKagAccountEntity-mandantId',
  'mandantKagAccountEntity-kagNumber',
  'mandantKagAccountEntity-kagText',
];
```

Each column needs a container inside the `mat-table` that defines how to display the property:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->


  <ng-container matColumnDef="accountlinevaluesId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> accountlinevaluesId</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.accountlinevaluesId}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="accountlineId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> accountlineId</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.accountlineId}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="mandantKagId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> mandantKagId</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.mandantKagId}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="mandantAccountsId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> mandantAccountsId</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.mandantAccountsId}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="period">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> period</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.period}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="accountNumber">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> accountNumber</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.accountNumber}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> amount</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.amount}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> position</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="mandantKagAccountEntity-mandantKagId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> mandantKagAccountEntity-mandantKagId</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.mandantKagAccountEntity.mandantKagId}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="mandantKagAccountEntity-mandantId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> mandantKagAccountEntity-mandantId</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.mandantKagAccountEntity.mandantId}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="mandantKagAccountEntity-kagNumber">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> mandantKagAccountEntity-kagNumber</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.mandantKagAccountEntity.kagNumber}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="mandantKagAccountEntity-kagText">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> mandantKagAccountEntity-kagText</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.mandantKagAccountEntity.kagText}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Considering you do want to show all data, there's no further mapping of the response needed, other than

```
this.dataSource = resp.success ? resp.susa : null;
```

Comment: Hello the first example is great, but not what I wanted exactly...

I want to output the whole JSON in the table.

With your example you can only output the mandantKagAccountEntity in my Mat-Table. Do you know how I can output the whole JSON with the nesting?

Comment: Your question states "how do I output mandantKagAccountEntity", which is what I answered.
I will update my answer, check back in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Again for your understanding :) The code outputs the whole JSON object (including nesting). Hope I can help those of you who have the exact same problem I had.

```
// Fill the table with data
private loadData() {
this.balanceListService.getDataForAllMonth(yearString).subscribe(
          (resp: any) => {
            let data = resp.susa;
            if (null !== data && data) {
              data = data.map((item) => {
                const kag = item.mandantKagAccountEntity;
                delete item.mandantKagAccountEntity;
                return { ...item, ...kag }; // merge two objects into one
              });
}
});
}
```